# How to configure IIS IP Blocker programmatically

Tags: iis, firewall, windows-server

is there a simple way to add IP to the restriction list in IIS IP and Domain blocker programmatically, at best from within ASP.NET code?

Comment: You can via the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` API, but your web app would need administrative privileges, which isn't a great idea. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @kev you need to use the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) and Active Directory Service Interfaces (ADSI).

below are some ways to block IP by programmatically:

1)

```
using System;

    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

    internal static class Sample {

        private static void Main() {

            using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
                Configuration config = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration("sitename");

                ConfigurationSection ipSecuritySection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/ipSecurity");
                ipSecuritySection["allowUnlisted"] = false;

                ConfigurationElementCollection ipSecurityCollection = ipSecuritySection.GetCollection();

                ConfigurationElement addElement = ipSecurityCollection.CreateElement("add");
                addElement["ipAddress"] = @"192.168.2.50";
                ipSecurityCollection.Add(addElement);

                ConfigurationElement addElement1 = ipSecurityCollection.CreateElement("add");
                addElement1["ipAddress"] = @"192.168.2.52";
                ipSecurityCollection.Add(addElement1);

                serverManager.CommitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

2)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Reflection;


namespace soccerwrek
{
 class IISWMI
 {      

  [STAThread]
  static void Main(string[] args) 
      {
         try
         {
            // retrieve the directory entry for the root of the IIS server

            System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry IIS = 
               new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry(
               "IIS://localhost/w3svc/1/root");

            // retrieve the list of currently denied IPs

            Console.WriteLine(
                "Retrieving the list of currently denied IPs.");

            // get the IPSecurity property

            Type typ = IIS.Properties["IPSecurity"][0].GetType();
            object IPSecurity = IIS.Properties["IPSecurity"][0];

            // retrieve the IPDeny list from the IPSecurity object
            Array origIPDenyList = (Array) typ.InvokeMember("IPDeny", 
                       BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                       BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                       BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty, 
                       null, IPSecurity, null);

            // display what was being denied
            foreach(string s in origIPDenyList)
               Console.WriteLine("Before: " + s);

            // check GrantByDefault.  This has to be set to true, 
            // or what we are doing will not work.
            bool bGrantByDefault = (bool) typ.InvokeMember("GrantByDefault", 
                        BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty, 
                        null, IPSecurity, null);

            Console.WriteLine("GrantByDefault = " + bGrantByDefault);
            if(!bGrantByDefault)
            {
               typ.InvokeMember("GrantByDefault", 
                      BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                      BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty, 
                      null, IPSecurity, new object[] {true});
            }

            // update the list of denied IPs.  This is a 
            // complete replace.  If you want to maintain what
            // was already being denied, you need to make sure 
            // those IPs are in here as well.  This area
            // will be where you will most likely modify to
            // your needs as this is just an example.
            Console.WriteLine("Updating the list of denied IPs.");
            object[] newIPDenyList = new object[4];
            newIPDenyList[0] = "192.168.1.1, 255.255.255.255";
            newIPDenyList[1] = "192.168.1.2, 255.255.255.255";
            newIPDenyList[2] = "192.168.1.3, 255.255.255.255";
            newIPDenyList[3] = "192.168.1.4, 255.255.255.255";
            Console.WriteLine("Calling SetProperty");

            // add the updated list back to the IPSecurity object
            typ.InvokeMember("IPDeny", 
                     BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                     BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                     BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty, 
                     null, IPSecurity, new object[] {newIPDenyList});

            IIS.Properties["IPSecurity"][0] = IPSecurity;            
            Console.WriteLine("Commiting the changes.");

            // commit the changes
            IIS.CommitChanges();
            IIS.RefreshCache();

            // check to see if the update took
            Console.WriteLine("Checking to see if the update took.");
            IPSecurity = IIS.Properties["IPSecurity"][0];
            Array y = (Array) typ.InvokeMember("IPDeny", 
                      BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                      BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                      BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty, 
                      null, IPSecurity, null);
            foreach(string s in y)
               Console.WriteLine("After:  " + s);
         }
         catch (Exception e) 
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.ToString());
         }
  }
 }
}
```

You could refer this links for more detail:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f6580aaf-ed47-4bb1-b976-6108595b8dfb/block-ip-in-windows-through-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: What about a powershell script or python, something that runs locally and gets a list from somewhere